# ASP.NET Web User Control - parameter passing to Database

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

Recently i have received an interview question.

You have created a Web **UserControl**.You have set the Databound to bound to a database.If you need to alter the datasource parameters which of the following events will you **override**?

`a. databinding    b. databound    c. preload`

I have answered databinding.But quite not sure about the answer.Kindly help me  in understanding the appopriate event.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are absolutely right. This is a quote from the MSDN (see link below):

> DataBinding: This event marks the beginning of the process that binds the control to the data. Use this event to manually open database connections, if required, and to set parameter values dynamically before a query is run.

[Data Binding Events for Data-Bound Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#data_binding_events_for_databound_controls)